# Getting rid of unneccessary permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, react-native, build, expo

This is what kind of permissions I have in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

But for some of the reason in the build, in AndroidManifest.xml file ( `build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` ) I have this permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Trying to find a way how to get rid of:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257412/remove-extra-unwanted-permissions-from-manifest-android

Answer (score 1):

When permissions get added like that, it means some library you depend on requires that.  The only way to fix it is to change the library so it doesn't, or not use the library.

Comment: The core package @expo is what writing these permissions...

Comment: THen you need to make expo not need these permissions, or not use expo.  Or live with having the permissions.  I suppose you can hack the build process to remove them and repackage the apk, but I wouldn't really suggest that-  if it actually needs those permissions it would break, and it sounds like a ton of work.