# How can we remove 3rd party framework permissions in Android Studio?

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, kotlin, permissions

Is it possible to remove 3rd party framework permissions in Android Studio? I cannot trust the security of 3rd party frameworks.

In terms of technical terminology, I believe that maybe ios developers can contribute if they have knowledge on the android side.

According to the iOS developers, it is possible.

For example, when using the unity framework, I want the code we developed to access the files, but the unity framework does not have this permission.

Despite doing a lot of research, I haven't been able to discover a pinpoint solution.

Comment: What do you mean by 3rd party frameworks?

Comment: On the Android side at least, you can remove permissions added by included third-party libraries using the steps at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257412/remove-extra-unwanted-permissions-from-manifest-android) - edit the `AndroidManifest.xml` to remove the permissions added by the third party libraries.

Comment: @SreehariK I'm talking about 3rd party add-on modules like Unity. All 3rd party software not written by the application developer.

Comment: @TylerV There is only one detail. Let's say our app needs camera access. Third party software also needs the camera component. Is there any possibility to remove only 3rd party permission? In other words, how can we remove the permissions that we have to use but that we do not want the 3rd party software to use, rather than the permissions we do not use?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Permissions are granted to your app as a whole, not to specific components within the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can but make sure to test well.

here's an example:

say you want to remove the permission ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION used in a 3rd party:

you add this to your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove" />
```

to see all permissions used in your app including 3rd party permissions simply tap on Merged Manifest at the bottom of your Android studio Manifest file.

Hope this helps,