# Apps gets rejected due QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission reason, but i am not using it in my app

Tags: android, flutter

Not able to find the proper answer of my problem. We got too many rejection for my app on play store.

> Issue found: Less broad app-visibility method should be used
>
> We are unable to approve your app’s use of QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission because the declared task can be done with a less broad app-visibility method.

But we are not using any permission in our code base and also check the same with third parties API.

Please provide us the proper guidance to fix this problem.

Comment: Hey, that permission might come from another library or so. To remove it, follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33105591/180538

Comment: hello, are you opening/triggering another application from your app; like finding out that if a particular app exists on device or not?

Comment: @BlazingR yes we using what's up, email apps..

Answer (score 0):

As in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring) at this [section](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring#package-name)

> If you know the specific apps that you want to query or interact with,
> such as apps that integrate with your app or apps whose services you
> use, include their package names in a set of  elements inside
> the  element:
>
> ```
> <manifest package="com.example.game">
>    <queries>
>        <package android:name="com.example.store" />
>        <package android:name="com.example.services" />
>    </queries>
>    ...
> </manifest>
> ```

So for example, whatsapp is the one we are accessing then below code should be sufficient.

```
<manifest package="your.package.name">
    ...
    <queries>
       <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
    </queries>
    ... 
</manifest>
```

With new enhancement related to permissions and securities, I also got into trouble for using *QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES*. This took my problems away and finally able to release app on play store.

Comment: if you are trying to replace a track in production, you need to change the gradual release to 100%. Only then your version is approved